# PHP code-igniter

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

I'm having troubles calling my external js files from my views php pages. The js files are saved in the "resources" folder in the root folder i.e "root/resources/scripts/myfile.js" just like the "root/application" and the "root/system" folder.

so in one of my php files in the views folder i am using this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="<?php echo base_url();?>resources/scripts/welcome.js">
```

and this php file is located in "root/application/views/welcome.php"
and still my page cannot link with the java script so i am stuck big time.

regards
k..

Comment: add a backslash or your site url at the beginning.

Comment: for my style sheet i used <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>resource/css/mystyle.css" type="text/css" media="screen" /> and its working properly

Comment: Are you sure about the filename case or path ? try to open it in your browser.

Comment: yes i am sure of the path because my css is working properly and both my css and js files are all in the resources folder as shown by the href for the stylesheet

Comment: are you try to open this file in your browser ?

Comment: Are you using a .htaccess to remove index.php if so have you added /resources to the exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script src="<?= base_url('resources/scripts/myfile.js')?>"></script>
```

Comment: apparently i was using <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>resources/scripts/messagecenter.js"></script>

Comment: so when you load the page what is the path to the JS file being echoed in the script tag?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your question and the comments below your question, it seems you are using "resource" in one example and  "resources" in another example.

Once fixed, view the source of the page (I use FireFox, as it makes the links clickable), search for "welcome.js". Once found, click on the link for that file. If you see javascript, it means the file is found, alternatively you will see a 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check if the resource folder is available,

The java script file is available and the file naming is in the same small or capital case, and server has public permission of the file and folder.

by the way your code has missing end tag

```
</script>
```